# IndexOutOfBoundsException on RecyclerView adapter with multiple view types

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have one list where i'm inflating for every next 5 element different view and that view is banner for advertisements. But now i'm getting an error in method `getItemViewType()`. This is how my code looks:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (jokes.get(position) != null) {
        // Here i should catch every 5 element in jokes array and change view
        if (position % 5 == 0 && position != 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_BANNER;
        }
        return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    } else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
    }
}
```

And this is method `getItemCount()`:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return jokes == null ? 0 : jokes.size() + jokes.size() / 5;
}
```

Note: I'm fetching 18 items from API.

EDIT:

One item is missing here at the bottom of list.

[image]

Comment: If the size is 18 then valid indexes are 0-17 inclusive. `position < jokes.size() && jokes.get(position) != null` **and** `jokes.size() + jokes.size() / 5;` is guaranteed to give you 20% more jokes than there are.

Comment: From where are you invoking getItemViewType() method? Please add the invoking call

Comment: `getItemCount()` makes no sense and is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, that is solving the error i'm getting, but now the VIEW_TYPE_LOADING is invoked and progress bar is loading at the bottom infinitive.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you have idea how could i solve this new problem where the progress bar is loading constantly at the bottom of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do something along the lines of :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position % 5 == 0 && position != 0) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_BANNER;
    } else if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
        // Last item. Return the loading view.
        return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
    } else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return jokes == null ? 0 
        : jokes.size() + jokes.size() / 5 + 1;
}
```

Remember that, when you bind the `VIEW_TYPE_ITEM` with a position, you can’t call `jokes.get(position)`. You need to account for banner views you inserted before. So `jokes.get(position - numberOfBannersBeforePosition)`.

Comment: Without `jokes.size() / 5 + 1` i'm not getting any error, but the progress bar is loading at the bottom constantly..

Comment: @Dusan so? That's what progress bars do. Regarding item count, as I see this my suggestion should be correct. If `jokes.size()` is 18, you want to have 18 `+` 3 banners (at 5, 10, 15), which is `Math.floor(18/5)`, `+` 1 item at the end. That's how I read your question.

Comment: I know that it should be, but why it's loading constantly. I have implemented EndlessRecyclerView and it should load new page. It loads second page, but doesn't load last item. Let me show you.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is implementing endless recyclerview.

in your recyclerview adapter write like this

```
 public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
 private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1;
 private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 0;
 private final int VIEW_TYPE_BANNER = 2;

 ......
 ......

 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 if (jokes.get(position) != null) {
    if (position % 5 == 0 && position != 0) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_BANNER;
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
} else {
    return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
   }
  }
}


 @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
 if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
 R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
 vh = new StudentViewHolder(v);
 } 
 if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING){
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
 R.layout.progress_item, parent, false);
 vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
 }
 if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_BANNER){
 //load your banner layout
 }
 return vh;
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
 return studentList.size();
 }
```

and maintain your logic of whether you should enable item or banner or loading from your main activity file

Comment: Yes, but i also have one more view.

Comment: For every 5 next element in list i have one banner where i'm displaying ads.